# How to block size change of QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Have table, when i resize window, table also resize with it, and blank spaces to the right and down appear. How to block resize of table when window change size? Table will have 6 col and 5 rows.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout

def getSelectedItemData():
    for currentItem  in tableWidget.selectedItems():
        print("ROw : "+str(currentItem.row())+" Column : "+str(currentItem.column())+" "+currentItem.text())

app=QApplication(sys.argv)

qwidget=QWidget()

qwidget.setWindowTitle("Verification")
qwidget.resize(800,400)

layout=QVBoxLayout()

tableWidget=QTableWidget()
tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)

#adding item in table
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,QTableWidgetItem("Date"))
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1,QTableWidgetItem("Rep 1"))
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2,QTableWidgetItem("Rep 2"))
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3,QTableWidgetItem("Rep 3"))
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4,QTableWidgetItem("Rep 4"))
tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5,QTableWidgetItem("Rep 5"))


tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(getSelectedItemData)
layout.addWidget(tableWidget)
qwidget.setLayout(layout)
qwidget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You can either place your `QVBoxLayout` inside a `QHBoxLayout`, and insert stretch items in both of them, preventing the `QTableWidget` from expanding and filling blank areas. Or, you could you can set the [resize mode](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QHeaderView.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeMode) of your horizontal and vertical header views, making the table cells expand and fill the entire `QTableWidget` area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set "setMaximumSize" and "setMinimumSize" to fix the whole table size

```
self.table.setMaximumSize(100, 100)
```